# Android - How to open an acitivity with the scale and fade effect

Tags: android, android-animation

I have an app and I want to open an `activity` using [this transition](https://youtu.be/RhiPJByIMrM?t=40s)
(Google Maps does this too if you open the settings).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

write your code in oncreate method of next activity

Answer (score 1):

Create XML file for fade-in animation, /res/anim/fadein.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
<alpha
  android:fromAlpha="0.1"
  android:toAlpha="1.0"
  android:duration="2000"
  />
</set>
```

Create XML file for fade-out animation, /res/anim/fadeout.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
<alpha
  android:fromAlpha="1.0"
  android:toAlpha="0.1"
  android:duration="2000"
  />
</set>
```

In your `Activity`

```
final Animation animationFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
buttonToNextActivity.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

  @Override
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  image.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
  }});
```

Same as it is find write in the `SecondActivity` and call the animation `onBackPressed(){...}`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line after starting the activity:

```java
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.youranimation, R.anim.default_anim);
```

For example:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent (context, YourActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.youranimation, R.anim.default_anim);
```

default_anim.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```

Change values.